# struggling to get msoffcrypto working in an executable build made with cx_freeze

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze

im struggling to get msoffcrypto working in an executable build ive made with cx_freeze.

1. i have an extremely basic python script

.

```
import pandas

import msoffcrypto

while True:

    print("  hooo ray   ")
```

2)which i build using setup.py build

```
C:\Users\jack.flavell\Desktop\New folder (27)\pnldisplayer - Copy - Copy\flaskj graph test\test\build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib>python setup.py build
```

my setup.py file looks like

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "data displayer",
    version = "0.9",
    author = "jack flavell",
    dexcription = " displays data from the excel file ",
    executables = [Executable("python_reader3.py")

    ]
)
```

3. i try to run the build but get an error stating msoffcrypto-tool not found"

.

```
C:\Users\jack.flavell\Desktop\New folder (27)\pnldisplayer - Copy - Copy\flaskj graph test\test\build\exe.win-amd64-3.9>python_reader3.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jack.flavell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 130, in run
    module_init.run(name + "__main__")
  File "C:\Users\jack.flavell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\console.py", line 16, in run
    exec(code, module_main.__dict__)
  File "python_reader3.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jack.flavell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\msoffcrypto\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    __version__ = pkg_resources.get_distribution("msoffcrypto-tool").version
  File "C:\Users\jack.flavell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 528, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "C:\Users\jack.flavell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 400, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "C:\Users\jack.flavell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 968, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "C:\Users\jack.flavell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
    dist = self._resolve_dist(
  File "C:\Users\jack.flavell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 870, in _resolve_dist
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'msoffcrypto-tool' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

4. as Proof that these packages seem to have been installed into my build i got into my build and show a few lines from dir

C:\Users\jack.flavell\Desktop\New folder (27)\pnldisplayer - Copy - Copy\flaskj graph test\test\build\exe.win-amd64-3.9>cd lib

```
C:\Users\jack.flavell\Desktop\New folder (27)\pnldisplayer - Copy - Copy\flaskj graph test\test\build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 580E-8B35

 Directory of C:\Users\jack.flavell\Desktop\New folder (27)\pnldisplayer - Copy - Copy\flaskj graph test\test\build\exe.win-amd64-3.9\lib

19/07/2023  13:43    <DIR>          .
19/07/2023  13:43    <DIR>          ..
19/07/2023  13:42    <DIR>          asttokens
...
19/07/2023  13:42    <DIR>          cffi
19/07/2023  13:42    <DIR>          cryptography
...
19/07/2023  13:42    <DIR>          msoffcrypto
...
19/07/2023  14:35    <DIR>          olefile
...
19/07/2023  13:42    <DIR>          pandas
...
              36 File(s)     15,079,671 bytes
              79 Dir(s)  18,852,990,976 bytes free
```

5. everything works fine if i remove import msoffcrypto from my script and rebuild, so making a build with that is the problem.

.

6. pip show msoffcrypto-tool incase that proves helpful

.

```
C:\Users\jack.flavell\Desktop\New folder (27)\pnldisplayer - Copy - Copy\flaskj graph test\test>pip show msoffcrypto-tool
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -illow (c:\users\jack.flavell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages)
Name: msoffcrypto-tool
Version: 5.0.1
Summary: Python tool and library for decrypting MS Office files with passwords or other keys
Home-page: https://github.com/nolze/msoffcrypto-tool
Author: nolze
Author-email: nolze@archlinux.us
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\jack.flavell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires: cryptography, olefile
Required-by:
```

7. so i feel like ive got all the dependancies installed propperly.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed in msoffcrypto-tool v5.1.1. https://github.com/nolze/msoffcrypto-tool/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v511--2023-07-20

I recommend updating the package and trying the build again.